# SELECT clause with self joining table

Tags: sql, oracle

Two tables:

```
//SKILL
SNAME
---------------------
C++
C#
C
JAVA

//REQUIRED
SNAME          REQUIRED
------------------------
C++               C
C#             reading
C              writing
C              reading
JAVA              C
```

I used this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT sq.SNAME,sq1.requires AS "requires" FROM SREQUIRED sq
INNER JOIN SREQUIRED sq1
ON sq.SNAME='C++';
```

but my output is

```
SNAME                REQUIRES
-------------------------------
 C++                     C
 C++                  reading
 C++                  writing
```

my question is if i want to find the skill that directly required by the skills C++, what query should i use ? output should be like this:

```
SNAME                 REQUIRES
-------------------------------
 C++                     C
 C                    reading
 C                    writing
```

Because C++ required C , and C required reading and writing. it's just like first level second level and etc.

Comment: Why you don't join your table with skill table and did self join?

Comment: just for fun - what's your output if you select sq1.SNAME instead of sq.SNAME?

Comment: @Snehal , is same what, so if follow like you join skill table how should i do? since you ask it

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but you can try like this:

```
select * from srequired
where sname='C++'
UNION
select * from srequired
where sname in (select required from srequired where sname='C++')
```

Comment: isnt possible to use join?

Comment: `select r1.* from required1 r1 inner join required1 r2 on
r1.sname=r2.required
where r2.sname='C++'` this will return only the result which the second query is returning in the answer

Comment: i think sure can use join only isn't? not neccessary use union right?

Comment: Did you try with join??

Comment: i used inner join. tried but fail. thats why..
i wan use join , and not union. haha

Answer (score 1):

Use CTE to make it generic. Levels may go deeper than just 2.
Use the following query to get required result.

```
with cte
As
(
Select SName, [Required] from courses where SName = 'C++'
Union All
Select courses.SName, courses.[Required] from courses 
   inner join cte on courses.SName = cte.[Required]
)
select * from cte
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The join criteria

```
ON sq.SNAME='C++';
```

Does not relate the two tables (sq and sq1) , and limits the result set to sq.SNAME = 'C++', which is why you are gettig only SNAME = 'C++' in the output.

The join would need to be as follows.

```
ON sq.Requires = sq1.sName
```

Then in your Where clause you need to specify:

```
WHERE sq.sNAME = 'C++'
```

You will then have sq.sName with 'C++' in 2 lines. sq1.sName with  'c' in all columns.  and sq1.Requires with 'Reading' and 'Writing'

To get the result set in a single output you will have to use a UNION or a CTE.  a UNION will give you the 2 levels you need.  a CTE can give you n-levels.  i.e if reading had another per-requisite.